# Resolve Angular resource promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-resource

I'm running into issues attempting to access the data returned through resource. It appears I am not resolving the promise before accessing the data as my data includes a `$promise` object and `resolved` property.

Here is my service:

```
angular.module('sampleApp')
  .factory('usersService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      var base = '/api/users/:userId/';
      return $resource(base, {}, {
        getLimits: {method: 'GET', url: base + 'limits'},
      });
    }]);
```

...and the relevant controller code:

```
var getUserLimits = function() {
  usersService.getLimits({
    userId: userId
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

This is what's logged to my console:
[image]
What I'm aiming to get from `data` is an object containing the `deposit`, `spend`, and `withdrawal` objects.

Comment: Why you are not calling object properties directly: `data.deposit`, `data.spend`, `data.widthdrawal`?

Comment: @SimoEndre Would cause problems inside a ng-repeat for example, since it would also ouput promise and resolve.

Comment: I could do that, but it makes my code less efficient. Ideally I would like to use `_.each` to iterate through `deposit`, `spend`, and `withdrawal` and perform some data scrubbing.

Comment: while returning data form server, place those 3 objectcts in on class..so that would be easier to do..`$scope.model = data.myData` then do `$scope.model.deposit` like so..I don;t think so that will cause any issue on the UI;;that will not get printed in `ng-repeat` content,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on your success callback you can use `toJSON()` function of $resource response so you will get plain object as you wanted...

```
var getUserLimits = function() {
  usersService.getLimits({
    userId: userId
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.toJSON());
  });
};
```